# Beanstalk puts the nginx conf file into the wrong directory

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I followed the documentation so to replace the default nginx.conf file. So the tree looks like this:

```
app_root/
├─ .platform/
│  ├─ nginx/
│  │  ├─ nginx.conf
│  │  ├─ conf.d/
│  │  │  ├─ my_custom_conf.conf
```

Although everything seems correct, after the deploy, the configuration ends up being moved from .platform to `/var/proxy/staging`; the eb-engine.log, in facts, reports this:

```
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/app/staging/.platform/nginx/. /var/proxy/staging/nginx
```

This means that the real config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is still the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html)

- `/var/app/staging/` – Where application source code is processed during deployment.
- `/var/app/current/` – Where application source code runs after processing.

When a new code version is deployed, `/var/app/staging` will be used to run build commands and test the settings. It is also used to test the nginx config file. If the deployment goes through, the code in `/staging` will be moved to `/current` and the nginx config will be moved to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the active config file. You can see this by using `nginx -t`.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-161 ~]$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

However, the content of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is NOT the default config. Whatever you put in `/.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` of your app directory will end up in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

In `eb-engine.log` you can see the config check in staging. If successful, you will see the `cp` command that copies the file(s) to `/etc/nginx`:

```
2022/09/07 14:23:03.027695 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2022/09/07 14:23:03.078615 [INFO] nginx: the configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
2022/09/07 14:23:03.078683 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
```

Comment: That's ok, I know this. After the deploy, I can find the updated app into `/var/app/current`. The nginx conf **is not** copied into `/etc/nginx` tho, but into `/var/proxy/staging` and I don't know why.

The configuration is correct, since if I replace the default one with the one I made it works as it should. At the moment I addedd another postdeploy scripts that copies the custom conf into `/etc/nginx` and restarts the nginx service, although I'd like beanstalk to do this.

Comment: I just tested this again. My `/.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` gets copied to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` every time I deploy (if the deployment is successful) without any custom scripts. So, like I said, it's not the default config in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, it should be your custom config. I would check the logs again and see if there are any issues with the new version (if staging fails it won't be copied).

Comment: As I said, these are the only logs about nginx:

`2022/09/08 14:10:55.739998 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure proxy Nginx
2022/09/08 14:10:55.741043 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/app/staging/.platform/nginx/. /var/proxy/staging/nginx`

The nginx conf is correct.

Comment: Understood. Does it run the config check `/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c` as shown in my `eb-engine.log`? If it gets to that point you should see the `cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx` as well. Just trying to figure out where this fails because if the deployment is successful it should eventually get to the point where it copies the staging config to `/etc/nginx` as you can see in my logs.